# Using static variable in ASP.NET web-service like cross thread

Tags: asp.net

Is it possible to use it with everything like in threads, with locking?

Main idea is to track whether some web-method is already invoked by same user, so we want to block more than X calls in a minute. We would keep some data in relevant HashTable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ASP.NET Sessions are dependent on cookies, which are easily circumvented by malicious users. Since malicious users seem to be your problem, ASP.NET sessions aren't the solution.

You could write a wrapper class containing a static Dictionary<UserID, List<DateTime>> allowing operations on the dictionary only with 1-2 methods and properly locking it.

eg

```
class UserLogger
{
    private Dictionary<int, List<DateTime>> _visits;

    public bool AddPageVisit(int userID)
    {
       // lock dictionary
       // add or update entry for the user,
       // remove from all entries the datetimes older than a minute
       // remove entries without datetimes
       // check if number of datetimes for the user > max allowed
       // unlock dictionary
    }
}

class RestrictedController
{
   private static UserLogger _userLogger;
}
```

Disclaimer: I just wrote this pseudo-code in the answer, it may contain typo's.

Answer (score 0):

There is a big disadvantage of asp.net session. It locks executing same sessionId requests unless session is in ReadOnly state. I haven't use it in that way but it think it can solve your task.

[ASP.NET Session State Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

> Concurrent Requests and Session State
>
> Access to ASP.NET session state is exclusive per session, which means
>   that if two different users make concurrent requests, access to each
>   separate session is granted concurrently. However, if two concurrent
>   requests are made for the same session (by using the same SessionID
>   value), the first request gets exclusive access to the session
>   information. The second request executes only after the first request
>   is finished. (The second session can also get access if the exclusive
>   lock on the information is freed because the first request exceeds the
>   lock time-out.) If the EnableSessionState value in the @ Page
>   directive is set to ReadOnly, a request for the read-only session
>   information does not result in an exclusive lock on the session data.
>   However, read-only requests for session data might still have to wait
>   for a lock set by a read-write request for session data to clear.

Comment: so there is nothing built-in right? what about our idea, some static list where we populate our data with locking mechanism?